# How can I prevent Backspace from navigating back in javascript?

Tags: javascript

This works in IE, but I cannot get it to work in Opera or Firefox.    I want to prevent Backspace from navigating away if and only if the current focus is the SELECT dropdown.

```
<html>
<body>
<select id="testselect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<script language="javascript">
    document.getElementById("testselect").onkeydown = function(e) {
        if(!e) {
            e = event;
        }
        alert(e.keyCode);
        if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
       e.returnValue = false;

        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) { e.stopPropagation(); alert("stoppropagation");}
        if (e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); alert("preventdefault");}
        return false;
        }
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 for helping me realize that "backspace navigating" works on keydown and not keyup.  I always thought I had to hit it once per page I wanted to go back, but now I realize I could just hold it down.

Comment: Oh, I installed firebug and now this sample works in firefox.  No idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out that Opera needs the event to be cancelled in the *onkeypress* event, not onkeydown.

Reference: http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=20

Answer (score 9):

**Using jquery - for only select dropdown**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     //for IE use keydown, for Mozilla keypress  
     //as described in scr: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/PreventDropdownBackSpace.aspx
     $('select').keypress(function(event){if (event.keyCode == 8) {return false;}});
     $('select').keydown(function(event){if (event.keyCode == 8) {return false;}});
}
```

**For all elements in page except input controls and textarea is as follows**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //set this variable according to the need within the page
    var BACKSPACE_NAV_DISABLED = true;

    function fnPreventBackspace(event){if (BACKSPACE_NAV_DISABLED && event.keyCode == 8) {return false;}}
    function fnPreventBackspacePropagation(event){if(BACKSPACE_NAV_DISABLED && event.keyCode == 8){event.stopPropagation();}return true;}

    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        if(BACKSPACE_NAV_DISABLED){
            //for IE use keydown, for Mozilla keypress  
            //as described in scr: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/PreventDropdownBackSpace.aspx
            $(document).keypress(fnPreventBackspace);
            $(document).keydown(fnPreventBackspace);

            //Allow Backspace is the following controls
            $('input').keypress(fnPreventBackspacePropagation);
            $('input').keydown(fnPreventBackspacePropagation);
            $('textarea').keypress(fnPreventBackspacePropagation);
            $('textarea').keydown(fnPreventBackspacePropagation);
        }
    }); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's trickier than I would have thought.  Depending on the reason you are preventing the user from backspacing away from the page, something like [this](http://www.dmcinfo.com/Blog/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/78/JavaScript-onbeforeunload-Code-Snippets.aspx) might work for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var bShowWarning = false;

        document.getElementById("testselect").onkeydown = function(e) {
            if (!e) {
                e = event;
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
                bShowWarning = true;
            }
        };

        function UnLoadWindow() {
            if (!bShowWarning) return;
            return 'If you leave the page your data will be lost.';
        }

        window.onbeforeunload = UnLoadWindow;
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the source code for the project from [this article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/CrossBrowserAjaxControlExtenderTips.aspx).  He goes into detail about how he had to contend with the backspace key in different browsers.