# Preventing backspace from navigating to the previous page when SELECT is focused and open

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, cross-browser

Before I get rushed telling me to search first.. I've tried. Without any luck and after trying multiple solutions.

This link looked as though it should work, but it does not.
[Stackoverflow link to preventing backspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773178/how-can-i-prevent-backspace-from-navigating-back-in-javascript)

I tried using that script. I also tried catching the key myself (using `keyup, keydown, keypress`) and `returning false, preventDefault, stopPropagation`, etc. Nothing seems to work.

Catching the key event does prevent it from navigating back when any other element is focused or simply the body being focused. This helps, but does not solve my issue.

I found another solution using pure javascript without jquery and it has the same effect (still navigated when select is focused and open).

If a user selects an option and then presses backspace it does not navigate back, but for some reason if the SELECT is still open, it directs them away from the page.

One solution I have considered is using a `body onunload` event to prompt the user if they want to leave the page, but then I have to deal with that when they submit to form or click a link on the page which is not an ideal solution.

The current code(of many different attempts):

```
$(document).on('keyup keydown keypress', function(e){
    var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
    if(key == 8){
        console.log('backspace');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log('keypress');
    }
});
```

Any help is genuinely appreciated. Thanks.

[Edit] I am using Google Chrome Version 48.0.2564.116 m

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem; i'm not sure why, but select elements weren't being captured by the $(document) selector. 
try `('*').on('keydown', function(e){...});`, this worked for me.